# Getting "Main method not found" error when using objects and classes

Tags: java

I am learning Object Oriented Programming but I get the error "Main method not found". Help?

Code:

// Demonstration of Creating and Using Objects and Methods

```
package cat;



public class Cat {
    
    int size;
    String breed;
    String name;
    
    void meow() {
        System.out.println("Cat: Meow! Meow!");
    }
    
}
class CatTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat c = new Cat();
        
        c.size = 40;
        c.meow();
    }
}
```

Output:

Error: Main method not found in class cat.Cat, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)

Thanks for the help. And sorry for the weird code. ;)

Comment: Create `main` in a public class.

Comment: How are you trying to run the code? It looks like you're trying to start the app with the `Cat` class, which doesn't have a `main` method.

Comment: Your main method is in `CatTestDrive`, not in `Cat`.

Comment: @Amongalen   Can you show me because I know how to create it but it gives me error so please show me what you mean.